# how to generate random number with no repeat same number again using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

how to generate random number 1 to 3 with no repeat same number again.
   ths is my code:

```
function randomFromInterval(from,to)
{ 
var rancalue=Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from+1)+from);  
return rancalue;
}
var rannumber=randomFromInterval(1,3);
```

Comment: do you just need a shuffle?

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google first. The first result when searching for `how to generate random number with no repeat same number again using javascript?` should answer your question.

Comment: @DanielA.White is correct - put the numbers 1, 2, and 3 in an array, then shuffle the array.

Answer (score 0):

1. create an array with all numbers in sequence
2. shuffle the array into a random order like described in the question [How can I shuffle an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript)
3. iterate the array.

Comment: Actually this is way better way of doing it than what I suggested. 1+ for not causing unnecessary checks having to take place.

Comment: You can just randomly select a member of the array, no need to shuffle, something like `arr.splice(Math.random()*arr.length|0,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind destroying the array, you can splice a random member from the array:

```
var getOne = (function(arr) {
  return function() {
    return arr.splice(Math.random()*arr.length|0,1);
  };
}([1,2,3]));
```

If you want to start again once you've run out of numbers, then keep the original array and copy it each time the spliced array runs out of members:

```
var getOne = (function(original) {
  var arr = [];
  return function() {
    if (!arr.length) arr = original.concat();
    return arr.splice(Math.random()*arr.length|0,1);
  };
}([1,2,3]));
```

Comment: can u send by jsfiddle.

Comment: Just love those drive–by down voters who don't have the courtesy to offer an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Using the shuffle function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6274381/145587) :

```
<script>
    //+ Jonas Raoni Soares Silva
    //@ http://jsfromhell.com/array/shuffle [v1.0]
    function shuffle(o){ //v1.0
        for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
        return o;
    };
    var random_generator = function(to, from) {
        var nums = [];
        for(var i = to; i <= from; ++i) nums.push(i);

        return function() {
            if(nums.length === 0) return null;
            return shuffle(nums).pop();
        }
    }

    var rand_unique_range = random_generator(10, 100), num;
    while((num = rand_unique_range()) !== null) console.log(num)
</script>
```

Comment: this is not working...

Comment: what do you mean it's not working?